# Finding Cursor Position anywhere on the screen?

Tags: c#, screen, cad

I'm currently thinking about creating a "digitizer" like Control for CAD drawing. In the 90s, I was trained in using AutoCAD, and we had digitizers. It still pains me that I don't have one at home.

[Digitizer, back in the old days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsevK.jpg)

However, having all the buttons on a tablet would greatly improve my drawing experience. I have already figured out how to create a virtual keyboard on the screen, so the only thing I need to do is connect my tablet to my PC as an additional screen and place the virtual keyboard with all the shortcuts. The only issue is that when I press a button, whether by hand or with the mouse, my mouse cursor is there and not where I was drawing.

So, I'd like to learn if there is a way to have my screen keyboard app "monitor" the cursor position (I know this is possible; I used to have a "mouse odometer" app that did exactly that), store that position, and move the cursor back after I press a button on my screen keyboard/template/digitizer app.

I tried, or sort of used:

```
private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Text = Cursor.Position.ToString();
        }
```

I can currently get the cursor position inside the application, but that only works within the application. I would like to have the cursor position available anytime, anywhere on my 3-4 screens, so I can store this position and restore the cursor to its previous location after pressing a button on my tablet.